# Passing Array of object to apex class LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript

I have array of object which contains two  different  objects data e.g  Secction__c and  Question__c

```
@track addSectionRecord = [
    {
      id: '',
      section: '',
      sort: '',
      Question: [{
        subQues: '',
        sort: ''
      }]

    }
  ];
```

Now i want to pass this array of  object to apex method like that
`apexMethod({apexList:this.addSectionRecord})` from JavaScript. Firstly how to declared the list `apexList` in apex.Secondly how to iterate the list in apex to get data  for these two obejects.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not directly using the two SObject types in your LWC?

Comment: yes. because  i have requirement  where  section__ is parent and Question__c is child object

Comment: I don't see that this would prevent you with appropriate use of nested selects and child creatiin/deletion/update.

Comment: In short its necessary , so   Is it possible for which i am asking above??

Comment: Yes. Create Apex classes that match the JSON structure. E.g. a class called `Question` with `subQues` and `sort` properties and another called `Section` with the various required properties including one called `Question` (really should start with lower case "q" and be plural for sensible naming) that is a `List<Question>`. There are rules around how these must be declared as `@AuraEnabled` to allow them to flow back and forth. See the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method). This applies to imperative calls too.

Comment: BTW "it is necessary" may not be the case at all (given that you were unable to answer this question for yourself) and you should consider whether you can rely on standard uiRecordApi wires from performance and data consistency perspectives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apexList` could be defined as follows:

```
public class Section {
  @AuraEnabled public String id { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String sortOrder { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public question Question { get; set; }
}
public class Question {
  @AuraEnabled public String subQues { get; set; }
  @AuraEnabled public String sortOrder { get; set; }
}
@AuraEnabled public static void apexMethod(Section[] apexList) {
```

Actually processing this uses a nested loop:

```
for(Section section: apexList) {
  for(Question question: section.Question) {
    // Do something here with section and question
  }
}
```

However, please note that `sort` is an Apex [reserved keyword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_reserved_words.htm). The above code renames sort to sortOrder to avoid compile errors. If you do not want to refactor the client code, you can instead use a Map/List:

```
@AuraEnabled public static void apexMethod(List<Map<String, Object>> apexList) {
  for(Map<String, Object> section: apexList) {
    String sectionId = (String)section.get('id');
    String sectionSortOrder = (String)section.get('sort');
    for(Map<String, Object> question: (List<Map<String, Object>>)section.get('Question')) {
      String questionId = (String)question.get('id');
      String questionSortOrder = (String)question.get('sort');
      // Do something with section and question data
    }
  }
}
```

However, this code has a caveat that some people have had trouble with automatic serialization, so you might end up having to convert this to a JSON string (at which point, you'll need to modify client code anyways, so you should probably fix it to use the first version I've mentioned here anyways).

```
apexMethod({apexList:JSON.Stringify(this.addSectionRecord)})
```

...

```
@AuraEnabled public static void apexMethod(String apexList) {
  List<Object> values = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(apexList);
  for(Object sectionObject: values) {
    Map<String, Object> sectionData = (Map<String, Object>)sectionObject;
    String sectionId = (String)sectionData.get('id');
    String sectionSort = (String)sectionData.get('sort');
    for(Object questionObject: (List<Object>)sectionData.get('Question')) {
      Map<String, Object> questionData = (Map<String, Object>)questionObject;
      String subQues = (String)questionData.get('subQues');
      String questionSort = (String)questionData.get('sort');
      // Do stuff here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you saved my whole week. thanks again